# How to trap spam sent from certain top-level domains?

Tags: linux, security, email, postfix, spamassasin

I'm getting a lot of spam from `eu` TLD
Maybe I could have put a rule set giving a score of say `2.5` or `3` for any mail originating from the `.eu` TLD; then this `score` + `other factors` could have made it cross the threshold of `6`.
How to achieve this?